# Remove Node From Priority Queue With Lowest Key

Tags: java

I have a priority queue set up as the following:

```
PriorityQueue<Node> pq = new PriorityQueue<Node>(100);
```

my instructions say that the key for the priority queue will be total = cost + tax. I have getCost() and getTax() methods but I dont know if they are needed here.

I am trying to remove the Node with the lowest key value. I am not sure if I need to specify the key when initializing the priority queue, or if doing

```
pq.remove()
```

will automatically remove the one with the lowest key.

Comment: See [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html#remove()).

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Okay so remove() removes the head of the queue. But is the head the one with the lowest key value?

Answer (score 1):

A `PriorityQueue` needs to be populated with `Comparable` elements, or else be supplied with a `Comparator` when constructed. So your `Node` needs to be comparable based on the total = cost + tax. If you do that correctly, the queue will put the smallest element at the top.